# how to initalise UIDocumentPickerViewController noting "forOpeningContentTypes" (from doco) seems to be deprecated in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidocument, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

When following the onsite IOS documentation for UIDocumentPickerViewController in Xcode 12.5.1 with IOS 14.5 deployment target I get an error:

```
Incorrect argument label in call (have 'forOpeningContentTypes:', expected 'forExporting:')
```

Any advice on how the usage of thie IOS UIDocumentPickerViewController is supposed to be used now?

My Code Except:

```
// Create a document picker for directories.
let documentPicker =
    UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.folder])
documentPicker.delegate = self
```

Snapshot of error:

[image]

Documentation for how to use document picker here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories gives:

Comment: Works for me - Xcode 12.5 (12E262)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
```

Comment: I didn't do that and it still worked... I imported SwiftUI though, maybe that auto imports `UniformTypeIdentifiers`?

Comment: this worked - actually how is this - does Swift functions available for a class kind of dynamically change depending on what you have as import?

Comment: @Greg That new initializer expects a [`UTType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype) which is not part of Foundation and/or UIKit. That's why you need to import UniformTypeIdentifiers framework.